# PHP - How to get correct first_name and last_name after login?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

So what I'm trying to do is grab the `first_name` and `last_name` from the database so I can show that when they login. But it won't properly work. I think I get the reason it's not working but I'm not entirely sure I I really need an answer

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['logged'])) {
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if (!empty($myusername) && !empty($mypassword)) {
            if($count == 1) {
                if (md5($mypassword) == $row['password']) {
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
                    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
                    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
                }
                else {
                    echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Password</p>";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Username</p>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Fill in all fields</p>";
        }
    }
```

Here's the database:

[image: SQL Database]

I think it's because the `$row` variable is only selecting the first row in the table. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calling `mysql_fetch_array` not `mysql_fetch_assoc`. So you can't use `$row['first_name']`. Instead use `$row[i]` where i is the index corresponding to the column first_name.

Comment: @sanketh `mysql_fetch_array` works... what you're thinking of is `mysql_fetch_row`

Comment: @sanketh That is incorrect. `mysql_fetch_array()`, by default returns _both_ numeric and associative keys unless you pass it a constant like `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_ASSOC`.

Comment: You're right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you misplaced a line of code.

```
if (isset($_POST['logged'])) {
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if (!empty($myusername) && !empty($mypassword)) {
        if($count == 1) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs); //Need to put it here
            if (md5($mypassword) == $row['password']) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
                $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            }
            else {
                echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Password</p>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Username</p>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Fill in all fields</p>";
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Though I would definitely discourage the use of MySQL as such, this would do the trick. I strongly recommend that you move to MySQLi as soon as possible.

Comment: This works, but now I have to enter my login info twice to successfully login.